# Protractor custom directive element is not currently visible in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to insert into input by using Protractor for testing. My input tag has a custom directive obtained from `materializecss` which is basically a datepicker (http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker).

My HTML:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <input name="dob" id="dob" input-date select-years="75" format="dd-mm-yyyy" changeformat data-ng-model="editProfile.patientProfile.dobToDisplay" data-ng-required="!editProfile.patientProfile.dobToDisplay" type="text" placeholder="(DOB)DD-MM-YYYY" class="colors" " />
    <label for="dob" class="active ">(DOB)<span class="hide-on-small-only">DD-MM-YYYY</span></label>
    <span class="materialize-red-text" ng-if="patProForm.$submitted && patProForm.dob.$invalid">Date of birth is invalid!</span>
</div>
```

I have tried following commands but could not succeed:

```
element(by.model('editProfile.patientProfile.dobToDisplay')).sendKeys('04-01-2016');
```

I tried removing attribute:

```
var remove_inputDate = element(by.name("rptdate"));
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].removeAttribute("input-date");', remove_inputDate.getWebElement());
```

and tried pushing data into ng-model

```
element(by.model('editProfile.patientProfile.dobToDisplay')).sendKeys('04-01-2016');
```

but it did not work,

```
var remove_inputDate = element(by.name("rptdate"));
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].removeAttribute("input-date");', remove_inputDate.getWebElement());
```

and tried pushing data into ng-model

```
element(by.model('editProfile.patientProfile.dobToDisplay')).sendKeys('04-01-2016');
```

but it did not work.

By using Chrome, it says element is not stable and through Firefox element is not visible.

Is this the correct way of inserting data?

Comment: I could not see this in your html 'newPatReports.reportDate'.Please share this html

Comment: Hey Riyaj....I have posted the complete div from my HTML...it is just the custom directive I has problems with......

Comment: If it is directive then this  check this one. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing